# Finding for which values of a parameter we have a norm in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

i am trying to find the values of λ for which $N_\lambda(x,y) \ = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+2.\lambda.x.y} \ $ defines a norm in $\mathbb{R}^2$ .

My main issue is that due to the square root function always being positive , the axiom (1) is verified for all values of $\lambda$  , axiom (2) is true and gives x=0 and y=0 ,as for the triangle inequality , i developed both sides but to no avail as no identification was possible.

Would appreciate any hints , thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say axiom (2) is true, you are going much too fast. For example if $\lambda = -1$, then $N_\lambda(x,x) = 0$ for any $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net thank you so much , i started off by noticing that in the case of 0 and 1 we would have the usual norms 2 and 1 ,then considered the case where x and y are both non-null , upon simplification i couldn't come up with any interesting generalizations  & got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

First, look at the domain of the supposed norm. It needs to be whole $\mathbb{R}^2$, so we have to solve inequality
$$ x^2+y^2+2\lambda xy \geq 0 $$
to assure that input of square root is appropriate. This inequality needs to hold for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, which after quick calculation gives us that $\lambda \in [-1, 1]$.

Then notice that plugging in $1$ or $-1$ doesn't work: we get $|x + y|$ and $|x - y|$ which are not norms.

From now on assume $\lambda \in (-1, 1)$ is fixed.
Write $N_\lambda(x, y)$ in a form $ \sqrt{(x + \lambda y)^2 + (1 - \lambda^2)y^2} $.
This suggest to define new coordinate system as follows:
$$ u = x + \lambda y,\quad v = \sqrt{1 - \lambda^2}y. $$
Now we see, that $N_\lambda(x, y) = N_0(u, v)$. Since $N_0$ is norm,
$N_\lambda$ is norm as well because it is the same function acting after appropriate change of basis.